# failing to pickle objects and import modules with python pathos multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pathos

Below are some toy examples to reproduce the issues I am having with pathos.multiprocessing on Python 3.5. One issue is that the parallel process fails to recognize what `Test` is, even when `Test` is not used within `test()`. I've seen some posts address the second issue saying that I need an `import numpy as np` inside the `test` function, but that isn't working for me.

```
import numpy as np

from enum import Enum
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool

class TestEnum(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2

def test(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return np.array(TestEnum.A)
    else:
        return np.array(TestEnum.B)

def main():
    inputs = np.arange(100)
    pool = ProcessingPool()
    outputs = pool.map(test, inputs)
```

The error I am getting is: `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <enum 'TestEnum'>: it's not found as builtins.TestEnum`

If I were to get rid of all occurrences of `TestEnum`, then the next error would would be that `np` is not recognized. I saw other posts on this site suggesting that an `import numpy as np` is required at the top of `main()`, but this did not work for me. The error I get when I try to import modules inside `main()` is: `ImportError: __import__ not found`

Comment: Can't test with `pathos`, using `multiprocessing.Pool()` works without Error.

Comment: @stovfl when I try running with `multiprocessing.Pool` I get this error: `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function test at 0x2b276ed23ae8>: attribute lookup test on __main__ failed`

Comment: How do you call `main()`, I assume you **don't have** a `if __name__ == '__main__':` entry point.

Comment: @stovfl Good point - I had been testing this by executing line by line through my IDE. If I add an entry point and call `main()` through it works with `multiprocessing.Pool`. Any idea why it wouldn't work executing line by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: If I add an entry point and call main() through it work

It's mandatory for `multiprocessing`!

> Python » 3.6 Documentation [Section: Safe importing of main module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods)
>
> > **Safe importing of main module**
> >     Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process).
> >
> > One should protect the “entry point” of the program by using `if __name__ == '__main__':`